# How to get image path from images stored on sd card

Tags: android

is it possible to get the path of all the images that are stored on the sd card of my android phone? also is it possible to check for other images stored on sd card or in the internal memory? I am currently doing this:

```
Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);  
        startManagingCursor(cur);  
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String str = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.e("#########",str);
        }
```

this seems as if  returns the directories names,
also I have seen this code:

```
File images = Environment.getDataDirectory();  
        File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){  
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
        {  
            return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png")));  
        }  
    });  
        String []mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];  

        for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
        {  
            mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
        }  
        Uri[] mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

        for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
        {  
            mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);  
            Log.e("###############","MURIS: "+mUrls[i].getEncodedPath());
        }
```

but this is throwing a nullpointer  exception .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a FileFilter for this. Here's one I wrote for returning a list of directories that contain images. From this, it should be fairly simple to modify it to return a list of images:

```
FileFilter filterForImageFolders = new FileFilter() 
    {            
        public boolean accept(File folder) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                //Checking only directories, since we are checking for files within 
                //a directory 
                if(folder.isDirectory()) 
                { 
                    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

                    if (listOfFiles == null) return false; 

                    //For each file in the directory... 
                    for (File file : listOfFiles) 
                    {                            
                        //Check if the extension is one of the supported filetypes                           
                        //imageExtensions is a String[] containing image filetypes (e.g. "png")
                        for (String ext : imageExtensions) 
                        { 
                            if (file.getName().endsWith("." + ext)) return true; 
                        } 
                    }                        
                } 
                return false; 
            } 
            catch (SecurityException e) 
            { 
                Log.v("debug", "Access Denied"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    };
```

EDIT: To clarify, to use this, you would do something like the below:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File[] imageDirs = extStore.listFiles(filterForImageFolders);
```

Comment: Hello kcoppock and thanks for the responce, the code works fine only one think I would like to ask you I added to the imageExtensions jpg,png extensions but this didn't returned tha dcim directory(the directory that holds the pictures taken from the phones camera) any ideas? regards maxsap

Comment: I'm assuming your directory structure is something like `DCIM\Camera` like mine is. So you would get the Camera folder, but not the DCIM folder itself, since the Camera folder is the one that contains the images, while the DCIM folder contains the Camera folder that contains the images. Does that make sense?