# How to get the Uri of a image stored on the SDCARD?

Tags: android, uri, android-sdcard

I need to get the URI of a image stored on the SDCARD.

When i want to get the Uri of a image stored on drawable, i use this and it works perfect:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.image));
```

But if i want to get the URI of a image stored on the SDCARD, i tryed with this, and it doesn't works, something is wrong:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/mnt/sdcard/car.jpg"));
```

Please, can someone tell me how to get the correct uri of a image stored on the sdcard?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/car.jpg"));? Let me know what happen..

Comment: Have a look on here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873496/how-to-get-image-path-from-images-stored-on-sd-card

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String filename = "image.png";
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/" + filename;
 File f = new File(path);  //  
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
```

Answer (score 17):

Always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of hard coding the path of external storage directory. Because the path of external storage directory may be different in different API Levels.

Try this:

```
String fileName = "YourImage.png";
String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;

File file = new File(completePath); 
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```