# Why is MediaPlayer doesn't start?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, ringtone

I have a sound that is supposed to start when the activity starts onCreate because this is an alarm. THe problem is, the sounds doesn't start. I've checked my volume, it's on.

This is the code for the media player:

```
    String tone = intent.getStringExtra("reminderTone");

    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        Log.d("log", "try");
        if (tone != null && !tone.equals("")) {
            Log.d("log", "tone is not null");
            Uri toneUri = Uri.parse(tone);
            if (toneUri != null) {
                Log.d("log", "mediaplayer starts");
                mPlayer.setDataSource(this, toneUri);
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is the log output

```
08-09 10:55:33.316  20706-20706/? D/log﹕ try
08-09 10:55:33.317  20706-20706/? D/log﹕ tone is not null
08-09 10:55:33.317  20706-20706/? D/log﹕ mediaplayer starts
```

I've already checked "reminderTone" there is a String URI in it.

This is how the String URI looks like. "android.media.Ringtone@ab91882"

I used another source of sound to test, and this one works:

```
    //play ringtone
    final MediaPlayer sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    sounds.start();
```

Do you guys know what's wrong with this?

Comment: check if this code is actually executing or not .... I mean if this has to run on a click then check if its `onClickListener` is called or not . More code will be helpful.

Comment: all the code is onCreate. I provided some logs and log output. as you can see, mediaplayer did get called. but it doesn't play.

Comment: try playing some local media file by copying it to asset folder and check that is there something wrong with your `tone`(source)

Comment: You tried with emulator? because the emulator doesn't have any ringtones by default.

Comment: @NaveenRao I used a sample local file to play the sound as shown in the updated question and that one works.

Comment: @yshahak no, I use my android phone.

Answer (score 1):

```
Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
MediaPlayer resourcePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, R.raw.my_audio);
MediaPlayer filePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/localfile.mp3"));
MediaPlayer urlPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, Uri.parse("URL"));
MediaPlayer contentPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(appContext, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/test.3gp");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Comment: While this appears correct, always explain your answer, so that the user may understand what this code is/what is does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your URI, make sure you use the proper URI.

> Note: URI string is different for every storage media that you are
>   calling, in my example I am assuming that you are looking for the
>   Music inside your raw folder.

```
int i = R.raw.sample; // we assume that we want to get the URI of our sound from our RAW folder.
String uri = android.resource://com.example.myproject/" + i;
```

For playing the music you can use this simple method

```
 MediaPlayer player = null;

 public void playMusic(int i) throws RemoteException {
            try {

                if (player == null)
                    player = new MediaPlayer();

                player.reset(); // optional if you want to repeat calling this method
                player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 }
```

The full working example can be downloaded here : [Music Player Tutorial](https://github.com/Ecobin/MusicPlayerTutorial)

Comment: as written in my question. My music URI String looks something like this depending on what is picked from the library: "android.media.Ringtone@ab91882" . I have no idea if it's right, since I'm not familiar with it. Do you think it looks like the right format for a ringtone URI string?

Comment: In my example the right URI arg would be  'android.resource://com.example.myproject/" + <Resource ID>' , so the string you provided will not work and it is not the right URI.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your String URI is based on local music file that is located inside of the app project. The one that I have is based on the local music file from the phone. Is it still wrong URI?

Comment: Yes thats the way to call local res, and for other storage media it would a different uri args.

Comment: this is an example of getting something inside the SDcard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296182/how-to-get-the-uri-of-a-image-stored-on-the-sdcard

Comment: okay. so my URI is probable right. cause I got it form the ringtone picker. so it should be right