# Getting the path where camera saves the image in android

Tags: android, camera

Is there any way I can get the path where an android phone camera stores the image,if the user has changed the default location then the updated location is to be made available.

Comment: You can use a `FileFilter` for this.

Comment: Look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873496/how-to-get-image-path-from-images-stored-on-sd-card

Comment: See you didn't get my question correctly, I needed only the images from the camera nothing else.

Comment: Then edit your question properly, as there you have mentioned the need to get the `path` and not any `image` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for several reasons:

1. There are thousands of Android devices, with hundreds of pre-installed camera apps, and there is no requirement for any of those apps to somehow publish where they store images
2. There are thousands of other camera apps on the Play Store, which the user is welcome to install and use, and there is no requirement for any of those apps to somehow publish where they store images
3. Camera apps do not need to store images in an accessible path, but somewhere else (e.g., internal storage, network)

Comment: So doesn't android distinguish between native camera app and other apps?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: Not in any fashion that has anything to do with where images get stored. Moreover, again, there are many, many "native camera apps". Relatively few devices ship the AOSP Camera app, if that is what you think the "native camera app" is.

Comment: I asked this because I can get to choose where my native camera app saves the pictures in camera settings, If I can get that data programatically, I don't know whether I am thinking in the right direction.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: Please re-read my answer. There is no requirement of a camera app to publish, to other apps, the path that the user chose to store pictures in. And there are thousands of camera apps, pre-installed or user-installed.

Comment: So you mean to say two things(Just clarifying)
1. You cannot distinguish the default android camera (meaning that which it comes shipped with) from user installed camera app by any means.

2 . There is no way I can know the path where any camera app stores the picture.

3.AS discussed by you in:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389427/android-broadcastreceiver-intent-to-detect-camera-photo-taken
there doesn't exist a way in which camera click button has been clicked when a foreground activity that consumes it has been running.
So is thr nyway I can get path/img camera(dflt) uses?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: "You cannot distinguish the default android camera (meaning that which it comes shipped with) from user installed camera app by any means" -- you might be able to figure this out from `PackageManager`, with difficulty, though I fail to see how it will help you. "There is no way I can know the path where any camera app stores the picture" -- no. Again, there is no requirement that a camera store a picture anywhere you can get to it. You are welcome to set up a `ContentObserver` on `MediaStore` to watch for new images, though these may not all come from a camera.

Comment: Is there any way to get location of the image OR get the path wer the image is stored by default camera app(or any app for that matter?)
Purpose - I need to know an image has been taken by camera and need to do some processing.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if  i follow the question correctly though

Try this :

Take a picture then go to gallery check the recent picture you took then go to its details it will show you the path

Comment: Please try to understand question before you answer.